# category in mysql displaying it once

Tags: php, mysql, database, group-by, sql-order-by

I have some data in a database and its getting outputted with an `ORDER BY category` and I was wondering how do I only display the category once?

```
  $SQL = mysql_query("SELECT id,name,category FROM table ORDER BY category,id");
```

So my script iterates through the table and sorts all the items by the category name.

I want to be able to display the category name once so then the rest of the values can fall within that category

I currently have something like this

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($SQL){
  $name = $r['name'];
  $category = $r['category'];

  echo $category; //I want to be able to echo this once
  echo $name; // this will be echoed many times depending on the category this falls into
}
```

Comment: Please look into [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo).

Comment: @PhpMyCoder what does PDO have to do with the problem of OP?

Comment: @PeeHaa Shouldn't we be encouraging the use of PDO over the outdated `mysql_*` family of functions?

Comment: @PhpMyCoder sure we should educate the users here on SO. But a comment like `Please look into PDO` says nothing to the OP. Also please take into consideration that the user might be working on an old website or PDO isn't an option for some other reason.

Comment: @PeeHaa It was succinct. But it was merely a suggestion. Nothing to get so up in arms over

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$category = null;
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($SQL){
  $name = $r['name'];

  if ($category != $r['category']) {
      $category = $r['category'];

      echo $category; //I want to be able to echo this once
  }
  echo $name; // this will be echoed many times depending on the category this falls into
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do something like:

```
$prev_category = "";
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($SQL){
  $name = $r['name'];
  $category = $r['category'];

  if($prev_category != $category)
       echo $category;
  echo $name; 
  $prev_category = $category;
}
```

So you will print new category only if it changed

Comment: Thanks, added initialization. But it's not an error, only warning. It's PHP =)

Comment: Thanks slava, but @PeeHaa has a working snippet which works great without any warnings for me :)

Comment: @Slava Yeah that's why I hate PHP. Not really, but you know what I mean :)